# delay app release on the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to delay the release of app sent to the Apple App Store after it is in review? Let's say I submit my app for review, but something comes up and the app needs to be released at a later (unknown) date. Can we have the app be reviewed, then when it is ready, have it be released? (Assuming the app gets approved after review)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this. When you release an app update just make sure you select "Hold until developer release" or whatever the actual wording is. When the app is reviewed you can release it whenever you feel. If this is the first version being submitted you can set the release date to a date in the future. When you are ready you can then se the date to be whatever today is.

Answer (score 0):

For a new application, just set the availability date to some time in the future. We usually do as far in the future as possible. To then release the app, set the date to the current date or earlier.

For an update, if you have selected "Hold for Developer Release", simply don't press the release this version button

Answer (score 0):

Now its easy to manage in the `iTunesConnect`;

> --> Manage your Apps --> select Your App --> Right and Pricing (top
>   right corner) --> change your app availability