# Cannot see "Hold for Developer Release" Option

Tags: ios, xcode

As I submitted an app this morning, I could not see this option which I previously see for submission of other apps just one month ago. I then "reject my binary" and try again, still no option to choose for developer release or automatic release. Instead, it was only introducing me to use Application Loader to upload.

Anybody submitting apps today? Could you see the "hold for developer release" option? Did Apple take away this option? Will my app be released automatically if approved?

---

It's a new app

Comment: is it a new app or an update to an existing one?

Comment: @spassas it's a new app

Comment: Its there for me in itunesconnect in the usual place are you sure you are looking in the right place.

Comment: Then there is no "hold for developer release" (and it never has been). You can set the availability date for your app some time in the future through "Rights and Pricing" in iTunes connect. Only updates can be held for developer release.

Comment: @spassas There was/is a "Hold for developer release" I have used it many times

Comment: From the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW2): _When you upload **a new version of an existing app**, you can specify when you want to release an app version to the store by using iTunes Connect version release control._

Comment: No "developer release" for new app? "developer release" is only for updating an existing app? Maybe I have been updating so many times that I forgot how it was when submitting a new app :{

Comment: @spassas I will change my previous comment it doesn't exist anymore but it did. I have always used this option in the past but it has been a while since I submitted a new app, so this could have been removed any time over the last year.

Comment: @Popeye I used the "hold for developer release" option just back in June. But I was just updating an existing app.

Comment: @Popeye There has never been an option for developer release in new apps. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149693/delay-app-release-on-the-app-store) from 2012

Comment: @spassas unfortunately I have no way to prove this but I am 99.9% certain I have done this in the past.

Comment: @Popeye You don't have to prove anything, it doesn't matter anyway since the question is answered for the present situation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it in the **rights and pricing** : You can change it and it reflects within 24 hours.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite what OP is asking. When you submit an update, you can choose to "Hold for Developer Release", which keeps the app in a "waiting" state until the developer chooses to release, *after* it has been approved. In my opinion, this is very different from setting an availability date.

Comment: No "developer release" for new app? "developer release" is only for updating an existing app?

Comment: @CraigOtis : You can set it to later before uploading the binary. So that, if it got approved and the availability date conditions satisfied then only available in App store

Comment: @CraigOtis : recently, I've uploaded an App. I've not encounter any of **Hold for Developer Release**. and also it doesn't get published in app store due to I set it for later

Comment: @KumarKL Sure, it works, it's just a little clumsy is all. But, as it sounds like since OP is uploading a *new app* as opposed to a *new update to an existing app*, it may be his only option.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I uploaded an app, a few weeks ago, I could setup a release date.

What I did was: set it for 2015 and waited for it to be approved. After being approved by Apple, I applied some final setup on my backend server and changed the release date of the app to "now". A few hours later, the app was available in the AppStore.